# Mac osx c++ .app cannot find a file fopen()

Tags: c++, macos, fopen

I have a folder in the same directory as my mac .app and in it is a file called test.ssm. This is trying to be opened by this function:

```
FILE *input_file = fopen("./data/maps/test.ssm", "r");
```

The problem is that the application keeps getting the code: EXC_BAD_ACCESS, because it cannot open this file. My project has been set up in xcode using a normal coccoa project. This is an opengl/glut application.

Comment: You should always, but always, test the return value from `fopen()` before using the file pointer that was supposed to be created.  That way, you avoid crashes because of accessing a null pointer.  Also, in C++, you should probably be using `<iostream>` rather than either `<stdio.h>` or `<cstdio>`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that a `.app` is a package, and therefore it is actually a directory structure as well, not a "normal" file. Your actual executable is inside the directory `YourApp.app/Contents/MacOSX/`.  Thus when you use a relative path starting with `./` to open a file in C-code, the executable is actually looking for your file inside the `YourApp.app/Contents/MacOSX/` directory, and not the parent directory that the `.app` package is installed in.

You can actually browse the directory structure of your `.app` by right-clicking on it and choosing `View Package Contents`.

If you are going to place files in the file-system that you would like accessible from your executable, either package them inside the `.app`, or place them outside the `.app`, and place enough `../` in your file access to get you out of the `.app` directory structure and into the parent directory where the `.app` is installed.

If you want your `/data` directory to be inside the `.app` package, then you would only have to add enough `../` to your path to get you to out of your `/MacOSX` directory and into the root of the `.app` where the `/data` directory would be found.

Finally, if you need to know the absolute path where your executable is located, you can always use the C-function `_NSGetExecutablePath` found inside of `mach-o/dyld.h` (i.e., you don't need objective-C).  From there you can modify the path to get at any other directory in the file-system relative to where your executable is by trimming it to the proper parent directory and then appending the path name to the file you want to open.

Comment: Yes I understand that bit but I have no idea where to put the folder. Wherever I put it, it doesn't seem to want to work. Do you know where in the .app directory i put it?

Comment: You would have to place the file in the same directory that the executable is in, or at least relative to it.  As noted in my answer, you can browse the package contents to see where your executable is by right-clicking on the `.app` and choosing `View Package Contents`.

Comment: I have put the folder in the same directory and it is still not working??? I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: The file `test.ssm` does exist, and you have the correct permissions on the file, right?

Comment: The file exsists and it has the right permissions. If i have the folder at the root of my hard drive and remove the dot in my fopen call, the application works, but I don't want to do it like this.

Comment: I found out that if I go to terminal and cd to the directory inside the .app where the executable is located and then run it from inside terminal it works, but double clicking the .app doesn't work, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Ok so ive tried your idea and it gives me this string: /Users/jeremy/Documents/Virus/build/Release/Virus.app/Contents/MacOS/./virus/../data/maps/test.ssm      - How would i make it work, as it has the executable name in the string

Comment: You are going to have to trim the string that `_NSGetExecutablePath` returns.  For instance, with that string, you will have to take out any directories and executables up to the parent directory where `/data` is located.  For instance, if you get `/Users/jeremy/Documents/Virus/build/Release/Virus.app/Contents/MacOS/virus` returned from the function, and `/data` is stored inside of `/MacOSX`, you will have to convert the string into `/Users/jeremy/Documents/Virus/build/Release/Virus.app/Contents/MacOS/data/maps/test.ssm`.  That means truncating off `virus`.

Comment: If `/data` was stored inside of the root of `Virus.app`, then you would have to truncate `Contents/MacOS/virus`, and then append the path to your file so that it looks like `/Users/jeremy/Documents/Virus/build/Release/Virus.app/data/maps/‌​test.ssm`.  You can use functions like `strtok()` and other string-manipulation functions in order to split up the string passed to your from `_NSGetExecutablePath` and create a new path that will get you to your file's directory.

Comment: Creating files in the `.app` directory is a bad idea, in general.  For example, I certainly don't run apps with root privileges except under duress, so I'd better not be able to create files in the `.app` directory.  That smacks of Windows-think!  Shouldn't you be using something under `$HOME/Library/Application Support/YourAppName` or something like that?

Comment: the point of not putting the files in the users document folders, etc is to make sure that the files stay with the application wherever it moves and to make it easier to distribute.

Comment: I may have found the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516200/relative-paths-not-working-in-xcode-c

Comment: Yep, that link is a genius, I got it working, basically you get a url(directory) and you use the command chdir() to change to that directory and then you can use relative directory paths again :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide absolute file path in Mac OS X, because Mac OS X is built to work with file dialogs or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

As said above, the `.app` is a package, or a special folder that the Mac OS X GUI treats like a file. The `.app` isn't what's being run, what's being run is `your.app/Contents/MacOS/your`, and the current directory refers to `your.app/Contents/MacOS/`. If you don't mind using Objective-C in your app (if you're not linking `Foundation.framework` already I'd advise you find another way), you can do this to get the path of the app bundle:

```
const std::string GetApplicationDirectory()
{
    id info = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
    NSString *bundleID = [info objectForKey: @"CFBundleIdentifier"];

    NSWorkspace *wp = [[NSWorkspace alloc] init];
    NSString *app   = [wp absolutePathForAppBundleWithIdentifier: bundleID];

    const char *str = [[app substringToIndex: [app length] - [[app lastPathComponent] length]]] cStringUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    return std::string( str );
}
```